# SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 75

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

This is my first query here.

**Issue:** I am getting subjected error while running the selenium webdriver command to access some website through google chrome and its related webdriver.

I use below versions of each entity:

-Python 3.7 (through Anaconda's Jupyter notebook)

-Selenium 3.14

-Google Chrome 75.0.3770.80

-Chrome Driver 75.0.3770.8

**Command Executed:**

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\pravshar\Desktop\DUCAT\chromedriver.exe')

Kindly help me out in this, Thanks in advance !

Regards,

Praveen

Comment: If this is the error message than your chrome version is not 75. The current version should be in the stack trace, you can also check it with `chrome://version`.

Answer (score 0):

Chromes normally its updated automatically, so you will need to check your current Chrome version on Help -> About. And update your driver with the current version

Comment: This will cause the Chrome version to be updated, it's better to use `chrome://version`.

Comment: Thank you so much guys, when i checked chrome://version, then i got to know that its 78.... and yes its keep on updating automatically.   now my command got executed successfully.

thanks once again  !